virtualizedlist: you have a large list that is slow to update only IOS
Even if i use such as useMemo or useCallback for memoization, if there is an image in the flatList and go to another page and scroll again, this error appears.
But strangely, it only happens on iOS and there is no warning on Android.
I have tried all the measures for image components, such as optimizing image components and using fast-images, but I don't know what the problem is.

Can you share your code, especially how you're using FlatList and Image?
